# Firebase rules continually revert to the default rule

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I would like to use this rule but firebase keeps reverting it

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{address}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow write: if resource==null;
    }
  }
}
```

I don't want users to be authenticated, there is no authentication for this site.   I am only allowing them to write if something isn't in that spot.   The rule works for a tiny bit but then stops.   This isn't sensitive data and data security isn't important for this app.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why does the rule continually revert to the default rule

Comment: It sounds like you may be running `firebase deploy`, which can optionally include storage security rules and replaces whatever you had if it does.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks, that's 100% it.  Been a couple of years since I've used firebase.   Changing storage rules on web instead of files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you may be running `firebase deploy`, which can optionally include storage security rules and replaces whatever you had if it does.